# Video JS and SWF click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, video.js, jquery-events

I'm using "video.js" and wrote some Javascript to have other videos that are playing stop if another one is clicked and played. This works well in IE9+, Chrome, Safari, and other modern browsers that use the HTML5 `<video>` tag.

My issue lies, in IE8 and the SWF/Flash fallback. The click event doesn't seem to be firing caught when it is clicked on.

```
 $('div.video-js').on('click', function() {
    var $this     = $(this),
        player    = videojs($this[0]);
        thisVideo = $this.children('object'); //get <object> for IE8 vs <video>

    /* 
      If videoj.js API is ready then...
      call the stop videos, and exception is the one that is clicked
    */
    player.ready(function() {
      if(player.paused() === false) { 
        //stopVideos(thisVideo[0]); 
      }
    });

  });
```

The SWF seems to be absorbing the click events that are meant for the containing `div.video-js` element. Although, when the div is clicked the video still stops, and plays, but I'm not sure why the click event is not firing...

The controls and big-play button still work, and fire the click event above...

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but it might be better to use each player's  `play` event instead, so you capture plays however they're initiated.

Comment: @misterben, thanks for the suggestion, I never though about using the Player class `play` event. But...how would I check if that certain video was the one that was played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `play` event to stop the other players. Since you're using jQuery you can use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to select all players except the one that's triggered the event.

```
$(".video-js").each(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  videojs(id).ready(function() {
    this.on('play', function() {
      $(".video-js").not("#" + id).each(function() {
        videojs(this.id).pause(true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/OcuXOCe/2/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks for clear and concise help. Greatly appreciated.